# How can we create a checker div board with PHP Programming

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter-3

Hi i want to create a checker board with data inside using codeigniter. As i program it i just can show a looping black white board like below

[image]

I want to the checker look like below

[image]

Hoping there's anyone in here can help me with this code. is it possible to create this checker div?

here's my code :

```
<div class="be-content be-no-padding" >

    <div class="main-content container-fluid">

        <div class="row be-booking-promos">
            <input type="hidden" name="<?= $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>" value="<?= $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>" style="display: none" id="token">
            <!-------- 1 -------->
            <?php
            $i = 1;
            $j = 1;
            $temp = true;
            foreach ($prays as $row) {
                ?>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 col-xl-1">
                    <div class="card" id="card<?php echo $row->id; ?>" style="min-height:150px; max-height: 150px;
                    <?php
                    if ($row->status == 0) {
                        if ($i % 2 == 0) {
                            ?>
                                 background-color: #999"
                                 <?php
                             } else {
                                 ?>
                                 background-color: black"
                                 <?php
                             }
                         } else {
                             ?>
                             background-color: green"
                             <?php
                         }
                         ?>
                         >

                         <div class="card-header" style="margin-bottom:-10px; color:white"><b><?php echo $row->name; ?></b></div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p style="letter-spacing: 1px; color:white"><b><?php echo $row->prayNeed; ?></b></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                $i+=1;
            }
            ?>             
        </div>
    </div>     
</div>
```

Comment: What is the difference between your two screenshots, rather than that there are more entries and different text?

Comment: @PhilippMaurer I think he wants a chess like board where row 1 starts with black, row 2 starts with white, etc.

Comment: yes like a chess board

Answer (score 0):

i have found the correct script for make the div like a chess board. it has to be inputed in controller since i using codeigniter.

So here's the code

```
public function  viewListPray()
{

    $idEvent=$this->input->cookie('eventID',False);

    $pray=$this->pray->viewAllNewPray($idEvent);

    $temp='';
    $i=$this->input->post('countItem');
    $color1="#999";
    $color2="black";
    $j=1;
    foreach ($pray as $row) {
        if ($i % 2 == 0) {
            $temp .= '<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 col-xl-1">
          <div class="card card-full" style="min-height:150px; max-height: 150px; background-color: ' . $color1 . '">
            <div class="card-header" style="margin-bottom:-10px; color:white">' . $row->name . '</div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <p style="letter-spacing: 1px; color:white"><b>' . $row->prayNeed . '</b> </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>';
        } else {
            $temp .= '<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 col-xl-1">
          <div class="card card-full" style="min-height:150px; max-height: 150px; background-color: ' . $color2 . '">
            <div class="card-header" style="margin-bottom:-10px; color:white">' . $row->name . ' '.$j.'</div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <p style="letter-spacing: 1px; color:white"><b>' . $row->prayNeed . '</b> </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>';
        }

        $data = array(
            'statusView' => 1
        );
        $id = $row->id;

        if($i%12==0)
        {
            if($j==1)
            {
                $j=2;
            }
            else
            {
                $j=1;
            }
        }

        if ($j == 1)
        {
            $color1="#999";
            $color2="black";

        }
        else{
            $color1="black";
            $color2="#999";
        }
        $i+=1;

    }

    echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash().'|'.$temp.'|'.$i;

}
```